# Will rsync copy extended attributes, ACLs, etc. reliably enough for Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, rsync

I am copying a TM backup to a new drive over USB by drag&drop per [Apple’s recommendation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380).  But since it is more than two terabytes, I am concerned about the risk of interruption.

If I try to resume with `rsync -avAX` will Time Machine be able to continue using it?  Another [question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183430/rsync-not-copying-some-files-with-extended-attributes) suggests I might have to ensure I have the latest rsync but will that be enough?

Comment: By drag & Drop? You mean in the Finder? That's usually not a good idea, so I'd be interested to see where Apple recommends this. When I've copied TM backups to larger disks, I've made a disk image with Disk Utility, or cloned with SuperDuper or CarbonCopyCloner.

Comment: All of those are also subject to interruption.

Comment: Also, can Disk Utility copy to a slightly _smaller_ disk if both are bigger in capacity than the backup set?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `rsync` doesn't support hard-linked directories (just hard-linked files), and Time Machine makes heavy use of hard-linked directories.

Comment: `rsync` won't create a Time Machine-capable volume, since it doesn't support copying hard-linked directories. Use drag and drop as recommended by Apple, I can certainly vouch for it: I successfully transferred my Time Machine backups from a 2 TB to a 4 TB drive. You could also create an image and restore that image on the new drive, then resize the volume (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204462/resizing-hfs-volume-after-cloning). The drawback is that you need a third drive to store the image.

Comment: @WGroleau I've used SuperDuper and CCC many times without interruption. DU  can't copy to a smaller disk, but I know that SuperDuper can.

Comment: If you are worried about the copy process being interrupted, sans a prolonged power outage, then common sense dictates that the devices in question be connected to UPS to protect against short term power outages, and placed in a safe place where no one can use, touch or bother them in any way while the process runs to completion!

Comment: Don't have a UPS, nor such a space to move them too.

Comment: Disk Utility refused to create the image!  And since the second and third Finder attempts failed (the third after a reformat), I now have SuperDuper! doing it.  No errors in 2½ hours, but for some reason it is going a _half_ the speed of Finder.

Comment: I have all of my computer equipment plugged in to various UPS and would never run such equipment otherwise, especially in a prolonged process. Even my MBP is plugged into a UPS, not so much for the battery, but for surge protection too. That said, if you do not have a secure space to insure your equipment is not going to be touched during such a long operation, then I'm not sure what you expect to get as a result of someone accidentally coming in contact. I guess you'd have to manually secure the cables to the devices. I have at times used rubber bands to do so, and it works quite well.

Comment: I’ve had to used the rubber band trick on a phone with a loose cable socket.  What I expected was the risk of what actually happened—the reason I asked about rsync instead of asking how to prevent an interruption.

Comment: The URL toward "Apple’s recommendation" is failing.

Answer (score 2):

Rsync, with the -E option, will copy the extended attributes and ACL of a file. The man page for rsync states:

> > -E, --extended-attributes   copy extended attributes, resource forks
> >
> > -E, --extended-attributes
> >                   Apple-specific option to copy extended attributes,
> >                   resource forks, and ACLs.  Requires at least Mac OS X 10.4
> >                   or suitably patched rsync.

Comment: That's an older version, though, that allegedly had problems.  Update, according to the item linked, changes it to -AX. I was just wondering whether it was reliable enough for Time Machine.  Hopefully, I won't have to find out.  Copy hasn't failed yet, but it says sixteen hours to go (after about three hours).

Comment: In some versions of rsync, "-E" preserves executability permission, and -X does extended attributes. Double check your version to be sure.

Answer (score -3):

Well, in OS 10.14.6 the answer is NO, but not due to a flaw in rsync.  Somebody bumped the USB cable when it was one-third done (estimating twelve hours to go).

I tried "rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31" installed/updated today by `brew`

When that failed, I installed another with Macports.  It gives the identical version info but is in a different path.  It too failed, same message.

Both of these claim to support ACLs with -A and extended attributes with -X

```
MBP-WWG:~ Admin$ sudo time  /opt/local/bin/rsync -aAX /Volumes/Nahshon/Backups.backupdb/ "/Volumes/Seagate Backup/Backups.backupdb"
Password:
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/Nahshon/Backups.backupdb/." failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: get_xattr_data: lgetxattr("/Volumes/Seagate Backup/Backups.backupdb/.","com.apple.finder.copy.checkpoint#N",0) failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1209) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Looking at the first error, I tried `ls` on the source backup.  Not permitted, even with sudo.  And `sudo chmod -RN` fails to remove the ACLs.  So, it must be SIP protected.

Update: as seen in comments, this error does not happen to everyone.  I do not know why.  I do know that before SIP, I occasionally had to relax permission restrictions on a backup set to get around a Time Machine bug.  But Time Machine always tightened them back up on the next backup.  Now, SIP won’t let me do that, but apparently at least one person does not have those restrictions.

Comment: Isn‘t this rather an edit to the question than an answer, considering that it ends with a question?

Comment: Ended with a question mark, not a question.  Fixed.  And the second attempt at copy hung during the prep.

Comment: RE: "Somebody bumped the USB cable when it was one-third done", just bumping a cable shouldn't be an issue, I've carefully picked up and moved USB drives while copying without any issues as the cable were tightly fitted,  but if the cable was pulled out then that's a different story not expressed. See my comment to your question.

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't, but it definitely did.

Comment: I just tried with rsync from Homebrew, and didn't get that error. So I'm not really sure whether the problem you see actually is related to the ability of rsync to copy xattrs and ACL.

Comment: It isn't.  It's that the xattrs and ACLs prevented sudo rsync from accessing the files and sudo could not remove the ACLs.  So I edited my answer to be more clear.  But I don't understand why Finder and SuperDuper can do it but root can't.  Or why yours is different.  Maybe we are on different OS versions—or maybe we _started_ our backups on different versions.

Comment: Nevertheless I didn't get an error for this, even with xattrs and ACLs on the directoriy.